# How to redirect existing post url after changing slug in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

My WordPress website was installed in root - example : https://surfends.com/  but now I have my website to a new slug "blog" .

Now it looks like : https://surfends.com/blog

I have to redirect my earlier posts to with new slug  :

Example : https://surfends.com/big-submarines/ ==>  https://surfends.com/blog/big-submarines/

I tried with :
RewriteRule ^big-submarines/$ https://surfends.com/blog/big-submarines/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

Can anyone help ?Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the easiest solution to be using a plugin like 301 Redirects.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/eps-301-redirects/

Comment: the url slug is fixed which is  https://surfends.com/blog but i want to redirect  https://surfends.com/existing_post to https://surfends.com/blog/existing_post